# Simple PHP code for using multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code an order process. I have 3 different tables (orders, product, users) in a single database (dbphesemaas).

What I've tried so far doesn't work:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('dbphesemaas');

$username=$_POST["username"];
$area=$_POST["area"];
$product=$_POST["product"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$dol_quantity=$_POST["quantity"];



$query="INSERT INTO orders (id, product_id, address, quantity) VALUES ('$id', '$id2', '$address', '$dol_quantity')";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Can someone make this code work, the id is a foreign key from users, while the product_id is a foreign key of product?

Comment: You need 3 separate `INSERT`s.

Comment: can you please give me an example please, I've been struggling with this for hours now.

Comment: I'm typing an answer as is, hold on.

Comment: Adam, looks like you've got some great help below. However, just so you know, questions phrased in the form "will you do this for me" are discouraged here, and is likely why you received downvotes. It's much better to ask for assistance and appear willing to implement suggestions yourself. Have a read of the _Help_ section when you have a few minutes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll do this next time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Error handling

You just connect and execute the query.

Well yeah nope - how are you making sure that everything worked?

Let's start off with error handling.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('dbphesemaas');
?>
```

Is the connection working? Did the database get selected successfully?

You can use the `if` module to check if it worked.

```
<?php
    // IF $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') did not work (note the ! in front of it)
    if(!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')){
        die('Could not connect to localhost'); // The message displayed. die() will prevent the rest of the script from executing.
    }

    // IF database "dbphesemaas" did not get selected succesfully (note the ! in front of it)
    if(!mysql_select_db('dbphesemaas', $link)){
        die('Could not select the database &quot;dbphesemaas&quot;'); // The message displayed. die() will prevent the rest of the script from executing.
    }
?>
```

Now we have the connection working. If something goes wrong, the script will stop being executed and throw a custom error.

### 2. Unnecessary variables

```
$username=$_POST["username"];
$area=$_POST["area"];
$product=$_POST["product"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$dol_quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
```

Now is my question, why? There is nothing wrong with just using them inside the query. The only reason why you only would make variables is if the old variable is very long (so the chance of typo's are bigger) and/or if the code is too messy in your opinion. Since there is no problem in this code to use the $_POST variable, we're going to scratch this piece of code.

### 3. The actual query

```
$query="INSERT INTO orders (id, product_id, address, quantity) VALUES ('$id', '$id2', '$address', '$dol_quantity')";
```

There are a few problems here:

1. You wrote the query, but you aren't executing it.
2. You are using variables (`$id`, `$id2` etc) inside quotes. In the wrong scenario, it's gonna insert `$id` in the database instead of the actual value.
3. Once again, no error handling.
4. No untainting at all. The user can add on into your query and alter the query, making a possible leak and the chance of being hacked bigger. We're going to prevent this with `mysql_real_escape_string`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
5. Looks kinda messy, but that's just a visual problem.

Let's fix these problems:

```
$query="
    INSERT INTO 
        orders 
    (
        id, 
        product_id, 
        address, 
        quantity
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
        '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) ."', 
        '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id2']) ."', 
        '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adress']) ."', 
        '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']) ."'
    )
";

if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'Succesfully executed the query.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Query not executed - MySQL error. <br>';
    echo '<pre>'. mysql_error() .'</pre>';
}
```

Using `'". (random php code) ."'` allows php code to be executed within a string. For example:

```
$variable = 'This is text '. strtoupper('this is capitalized since strtoupper makes this capital. note that this is inside the string.') .' and this is once again lowercase.';
```

### 4. Keep this for the future

The way I wrote these codes are useful for the future. Keep the use tabs every time you open/add a new bracket (`{`).

Further info - the default mysql_* functions are going to be deprecated as of PHP 5.5 - Use MySQLi in the future, it's the improved version. Info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

### 5. For your actual problem

One `mysql_query` can only execute one query. You can do this:

```
$queries = array();
$errors = array();

$queries[] = 'INSERT INTO ... '; // using $variable[] will add another entry to the $variable array.
$queries[] = 'INSERT INTO ... ';
$queries[] = 'UPDATE bla SET ...';

foreach($queries as $query){

    // Foreach will seperate the entries in an array

    // IF mysql query failed
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        $errors[] = mysql_error(); // We'll add the errors to an array aswell.
    }
}

// Check if there are entries in the $failures array.
if(count($errors) > 0){
    echo 'We had some MySQL errors.';

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $failure){
        echo '<li>'. $failure .'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

}
else
{
    echo 'No errors - MySQL queries executed succesfully.';
}
```

Hope this helps you on your way.

Comment: @halfer , i forgot to ask this, the $id and $id2 are suppose to be from another table, $id is from users and $id2 is from products, how am I suppose to retrieve and insert this values to the order table?

Comment: @Adam: I can't see where they are defined, either in Thew's answer, or in your question. Firstly, don't call the variables `$id1` and `$id2`, call them something meaningful like `$idUser` and `$idProduct`. Where they come from depends on your form and your program design. If you are coding an order system, it _might_ come from `$_POST["product"]` if this is a primary key (and not a product name). Again, your element name could do with a better name - if this is indeed a primary key, use `product_id` rather than `product`.

Comment: In terms of `$_POST["username"]`, it depends on where this comes from. If you want the order to be made against the currently logged-in user, you'd normally read this from your session rather than from your form. But, I don't know how you've implemented your form.

Comment: my form is just a simple html script asking for the product name and quantity and address, including the username, i havent yet tried the getting the userid from the session, but still i dont know how to retrieve a foreign key at the same time insert it to a table. I'll change my variables to the one you suggested.

Comment: @halfer: how do i retrieve and insert foreign keys from two alternate tables. I haven't yet tried using the logged-in user sessions, but if so, how do I put that in a php script?

Comment: For the foreign key, just do a `SELECT whatever_key FROM foreign_table WHERE primary_key = ?` and run it like you would an ordinary query. That said, as I mentioned before, if you can change `$_POST["product"]` to `$_POST["product_id"]` then that is a foreign key itself, and can be used directly.

Comment: As for user sessions, that's too broad to answer on this question, and as it stands too broad for Stack Overflow entirely, imo. I recommend you search for "PHP user sessions tutorial", there's probably quite a few out there `:)`.

Comment: @halfer: it shows this error when i tried your query "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbphesemaas`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `fdz7l_users` (`id`))"

Comment: also the $_POST['product_id'] and $_POST['id'] are both undefined. can you assist me with this please.

Comment: I think you need to stop your current project, and get some design done. Your questions are way too broad, unfortunately. I don't want to put you off asking questions here, but to answer your last one, I would need to understand your whole system design. If those values are missing in your form, then you will need to add them. Where they come from will depend on how the form is rendered and what it is meant to do. I would recommend reading a book on PHP/MySQL development and doing some solid study - it will really help you in the long term.

Comment: Your constraint error indicates that you are missing a user ID, and you've instructed your database to reject rows that do not contain a valid user foreign key. You could hardwire one for now, and then fix it when you've got sessions working.