# mysqli bind_param fails or throws non-object error?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

Hi I am converting over from normal way of doing things to this 'new' object way... Im not going to lie im quite confused and hope someone could help me here...

Below is my code

```
<?php
    include("common/functions.inc.php");
    $mysqli = new MySQLi($settings['mysql']['host'], $settings['mysql']['user'], $settings['mysql']['pass'], $settings['mysql']['db']);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_survey (fld_submituid, fld_q1answer, fld_q2answer, fld_q3answer, fld_q4answer, fld_q5answer, fld_q6answer) VALUES (:uid, :q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :q5, :q6)")) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":uid",$uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":q1",$q1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);    
        $stmt->bindParam(":q2",$q2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $stmt->bindParam(":q3",$q3, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $stmt->bindParam(":q4",$q4, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $stmt->bindParam(":q5",$q5, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $stmt->bindParam(":q6",$q6, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $uid = 1;
        $q1 = "q1";
        $q2 = "q2";
        $q3 = "q3";
        $q4 = "q4";
        $q5 = "q5";
        $q6 = "q6";

        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        if($stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
    }
```

I still do not why my code is failing, anyone help me please? Thank you

Comment: 1 - Don't check for submits with `isset($_POST["btn_submit"])`. Use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`.  
2 - Why are you making unneccesairy variables?  

Please read point 1-4 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19337295/528370) to improve and stabilize your code.

Comment: I was going to create a function to mysqli_real_escape but after reading up on this this is the way im going, and have yet to modify a lot of code, but thanks :)

Comment: 1. mysqli_report have to be added **BEFORE CONNECT**, not execute. 2. there is **no such method** like `bindParam` in mysqli. 3. Proper example is shown on the manual page. Why don't you just follow it?

Answer (score 3):

mysqli doesn't support named placeholders.

Please read [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and follow the proper syntax

To have an error message from `prepare()`, add this line before connect:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: And if you wish to use the named placeholders, take a look into PDO:http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Great, 

I'm reading at this

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

Could you explain the 'sssd' part to me? I just dont get it, what do the letters mean?

Thanks

Comment: @JoshBlue why do you want me to read aloud for you [this very manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters) ?

Comment: s - string? d - double?? I got it!

Comment: "Not working" is not a [worthless] explanation. Does it emit any errors? By the way, what are these "both" methods? I've showed you only one so far.